# How to trigger an email when sonarqube code analysis report is generated?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am looking for an overall code analysis report after running the sonarqube code review. Everytime I trigger the sonarqube analysis through maven. Hence I need some automatic reporting which can be sent through a notification.  Please advise?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to use Jenkins to run your Sonar analysis and Jenkins post build actions will allow you to send report

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ,but as per policy have to use maven is there any soultion for maven??

Comment: Can this help? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435455/sending-email-with-attachment-using-maven , you mean sending an email trough Maven? can you just build a small maven project or a mojo to send an email, should not be too hard...